# Making log file in batch after a MOVE operation

Tags: logging, batch-file, move

I just need some help with creating a log file for a batch script I'm running at the moment. As I move files from 1 server to another it would be handy to know when things have been moved over.

At the moment I've tried a few things like:

```
if %errorlevel% GTR 0 (echo MOVE FAILURE>Logs\log.txt) else (echo MOVE SUCCESSFUL>Logs\log.txt)
```

But this just gets to be sloppy code, as I would have to put it after every line, and it doesn't tell me the name of the file I have just moved.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
@Echo OFF

cd C:\Test

MOVE "Home\*.*" "Work"

Echo COMPLETE
Pause
```

Of course there's more lines, about another 20, but for the sake of testing I just have the one folder, and the folder names are just placebos.

Now I can use the default return screen by the Move Command

```
C:\Test\Home\Test.txt
    1 file(s) moved.
```

But I don't know how to move that output into a simple .txt file that I can just keep a record off.

By the way if there a better way or better program to write it in let me know, and I'll investigate!

Comment: Does this work? `MOVE stuff.* some_dir >log.txt 2>&1`

Comment: You should investigate the ROBOCOPY command. It has options to move files, and it can give a complete log of what was done.

Comment: @dbenham Robocopy seems like a briliant idea, but How can I make the code neat - becuase i've got 20 other things to include!

Comment: @dbenham Can you put your suggestsion of ROBOCOPY down as the answer, as it worked fine :) not perfect but best asnwer :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courtesy of dbenham : You should investigate the ROBOCOPY command. It has options to move files, and it can give a complete log of what was done.

```
robocopy "Home" "Office" /MOV /NJH /NP /NS /NC /LOG+:"Desktop\Log-%date:/=%-%time:~0,2%;%time:~3,2%.txt"
```

is what I've used! Works fine, not perfect but give me oversight into what has been moved!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "fname=" 
for %%i in (*) do set "fname=%%~i"&call:process
goto:eof

:process
MOVE "%fname%" "test"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (echo MOVE "%fname%" FAILURE) else echo MOVE "%fname%" SUCCESSFUL
goto:eof
```

Comment: Again i cannot get that file to work aswell.. even bby setting a fname?

Comment: the `for` loop has the pattern `*.exe` , sorry again. I have a serious lack of coffee ....

Comment: Sorry this renamed my files and got rid of their extensions. I'll use ROBOCopy :) thanks for your help!