# Output list of matching files to .txt then move files, use txt to later return files to original folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

There is really 2 parts to this question:

- I have a folder full of files that I need to temporarily move to a
  new location.
- However I will later need to move the files back to their original
  location(s).

*I have a single folder, full of files and folders that looks like this*:

```
C:\VIDEO\My Video 1\My Video 1.mkv
C:\VIDEO\MyVideo2\MyVideo2.mkv
C:\VIDEO\My.Video.3\My.Video.3.mkv
```

I need to:

```
1. Recursively find all *.mkv files within C:\VIDEO folder
2. Output a list of the existing Dir structure/file and folder names/paths to a .txt file
3. Then Move all *.mkv files from C:\VIDEO to another folder C:\Temp
(I do not want to retain the original folder structure during this move)
```

At a later time I then need to:

```
4. Search for all *.mkv files in C:\Temp
5. Use the .txt file to help move each *.mkv file back into their original location
```

I guess this will probably require 2 separate batch files.

*Here is my current progress:*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Setup
set "SourcePath=C:\VIDEO"
set "DestPath=C:\Temp"

:: Output Items To Txt File
for /f "delims=\" %%A in ('dir "%SourcePath%"\*.mkv') DO echo "%SourcePath%">>"%DestPath%"\output.txt

:: Move Matching Items
for /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('dir "%SourcePath%"\*.mkv') DO move /y "%SourcePath%\%%a" "%DestPath%"
```

Can somebody please help?

Comment: `robocopy /?`. `/s /move` should be helpful. As this keeps the folder structure, you later simply have to `robocopy` back (no need for a text file to save original locations).

Comment: @Stephan but I do not want to retain the folder structure after the files are moved. I want all *.mkv to be moved directly into the C:\Temp folder. Anything else not matching this extension to stay put where it is already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making log file in batch after a MOVE operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062367/making-log-file-in-batch-after-a-move-operation)

Answer (score 1):

You want to move a tree to a flat destination (knowing you later want to move it back and have to recreate the tree)? Why on earth would one do that...

But ok:

```
@echo off
set "SourcePath=C:\VIDEO"
set "DestPath=C:\Temp"
echo @echo off > MoveBack.bat
for /r "%SourcePath%" %%A in (*.mkv) do (
  ECHO move "%%~fA" "%DestPath%\"
  >> MoveBack.bat echo move "%DestPath%\%%~nxA" "%%~dpA"
)
echo done. To move them back, execute MoveBack.bat
```

Instead of logging the moved files to a text file and later iterate over that file, it's easier to just build a "restore" script.

For a description of the `%%~` modifiers, read the output of `for /?`

NOTE: I disarmed the `move` command for security reasons. If you are sure it works as intended, remove the `ECHO`.

Note: it's possible to have duplicate file names in a folder tree. This script does not account for that (saying: you may lose data in this case)

Answer (score 0):

The final product:

```
@echo on
set "SourcePath=H:\FIXED"
set "DestPath=H:\Temp"
echo @echo on > MoveBack.bat
for /r "%SourcePath%" %%A in (*.mkv) do (
  move "%%~fA" "%DestPath%\"
  >> MoveBack.bat echo move "%DestPath%\%%~nxA" "%%~dpA"
)
@echo done. To move them back, execute MoveBack.bat
```

is now working.

Comment: The opening parenthesis `(` has to be on the same physical line as `do`.

Comment: you missed a `%` in `%SourcePath` and `%DestPath`

Comment: What an easy fix! It is working now, although any idea why the final line is repeated twice? Too many "echo" I guess but which one to remove?

Comment: That's called "command repetition", caused by `@echo on`. Change to `@echo off`.

Comment: how about adding a line to the loop like `echo Now moving %%~fA` ?

Comment: or you insert another `echo on` after the loop. Or - if the `echo done. ...` line is the last one in the script, change it to `@echo done. ...`

Comment: Fixed it above with @echo done... etc. on the final line. Thanks!

Comment: @Stephan How can I change the code to use Robocopy for the move(s), so that date/time for the folders can be preserved?