# Use .txt logfile to move files into multiple folders

Tags: regex, batch-file, cmd

I have a `logfile.txt` that contains the following lines of text:

```
C:\VIDEO\My Video 1\My Video 1.mkv
C:\VIDEO\MyVideo2\MyVideo2.mkv
C:\VIDEO\My.Video.3\My.Video.3.mkv
```

and a folder C:\Temp that contains the files:

```
My Video 1.mkv
MyVideo2.mkv
My.Video.3.mkv
```

I need to use the `logfile.txt` to match the respective filename.mkv that is listed in the logfile, then move the file back to its correct folder (as shown in the logfile).

e.g  `My Video 1.mkv` should be moved to `C:\VIDEO\My Video 1\`

The relevant folders already exist within `C:\VIDEO` so do not require creation.

How can I write a batch file for this?

I am starting off right now with something like this, but I am now stuck:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "logfile=C:\Temp\logfile.txt"
set "SourcePath=C:\Temp"
set "DestPath=C:\VIDEO"

if exist ..\DestPath\nul rd /s /q ..\DestPath
if not exist ..\DestPath\nul md ..\DestPath

for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "%logfile%"') do move "%SourcePath%\%%a" "%DestPath%"
```

Can someone please assist?

Comment: I don't know why you're using `/n` but if you were to keep it, the first token would be the line number! I'm also a little confused about `..\DestPath`, I'm unsure of how it's relevant to anything else in the script.

Comment: Why would you use a batch file for that? Literally any other programming language would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

quite simple, if you use `%%~` modifiers (see `for /?`)

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%logfile%) do ECHO move "%SourcePath%\%%~nxA" "%%~dpA"
```

NOTE: I disarmed the `move` command for security reasons. When you are sure it works as intended, remove the `ECHO`.

(Have you seen my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56714712/output-list-of-matching-files-to-txt-then-move-files-use-txt-to-later-return-f)?)

Answer (score 1):

Also easy in PowerShell. When you are confident that the files will be moved correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` command.

=== Move-FilesToMultipleFolders.ps1

```
Get-Content 'C:\src\t\logfile.txt' |
    ForEach-Object { Move-Item -Path "C:\Temp\$(Split-Path $_ -Leaf)" $_ -WhatIf }
```

An alias should not be put into a script, but here is a one-liner.

```
gc 'C:\src\t\logfile.txt' | % { move "C:\Temp\$(Split-Path $_ -le)" $_ -WhatIf }
```

If you create a .bat file script to run it, put both the .bat and .ps1 file in the same directory.

=== Move-MultipleFilesToFolders.bat

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "%~dp0Move-MultipleFilesToFolders.ps1"
```

Answer (score 0):

So overall Stephan you are saying the answer is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "logfile=C:\Temp\logfile.txt"
set "SourcePath=C:\Temp"

@echo on & for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%logfile%) do move "%SourcePath%\%%~nxA" "%%~dpA"
```

to make it work

Comment: @lit to run that in Powershell easily do I simply create a .bat file and enter powershell -File "litPowershellAnswer.ps1" at the prompt?

Comment: @Stephan Is there anyway to code for moving the files back while retaining the original dates/timestamps?

Comment: @Stephan I replied to your previous question, unfortunately I lost my original login so have had to respond using this. Unfortunately I cannot get the answer to your previous question to work. Please see the other question for my comments/issues about it.

Comment: `move` doesn't touch the time stamp.

Comment: @Stephan ah yes I see now. It is the folder that is the issue, not the file. The file retains the original timestamp, but the folder does not. Is it possible then to copy the item back into the folder without the folder date/time being modified? Or e.g. copy date/time stamp from the file to overwrite that on folder properties? In case you are wondering why, it helps with sorting, otherwise all folders just end up with the exact same date and time.

Comment: @StrangerThings - Use `powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "...`

Comment: @Stephan How can I change the move command code to use Robocopy instead for the move(s), so that date/time for the folders can be preserved?